# how to migrate to a php page from html page

Tags: php, html

Hi guys i have website that is running on localhost. There is a page name contacts.html. I have some anchor tags that are not working properly.

```
    <div class="logo">
        <h1><a href="index.php">Hope</a></h1>
    </div>
```

when ever I click on this tag it shifted me to index.html while I want to migrate to index.php. I even tried this but it is not going to index.php

```
    <h1><a href="http://localhost:8080/live4others/index.php">Hope</a></h1>
```

how can I migrate to index.php

Comment: Is your contacts.html page in the "live4others" folder as well?

Comment: yes he is in folder

Comment: can you show us your directory structure

Comment: @Azeem112 and index.php code

Comment: live4others\ index.php and contacts.html and index.html

Comment: code in index.php is about +300 lines

Comment: i hope htm and php files are inside of folder. rename it

Comment: well there is nothing wrong with your code as well as anchor tag. there may be another reason

Answer (score 0):

If you have both index.php and index.html in the same folder, server settings might make Apache (which I assume you're using) load index.html before index.php, regardless of the link you set. Take a look at the server settings.